# Marshall weird C++ structure in C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling

I've been trying to marshall this structure in C#, but I have troubles with two last lines in it.

```
typedef struct _modenv_
{
  long lMajor;         /* major version of kernel */
  long lMinor;         /* minor version of kernel */
  long lRelease;       /* release version of kernel */

  long lResultSize;    /* sResult buffer size */

  long (__stdcall *lPGSM_ExecuteKernel) (struct _modenv_ *PGEnv, char *sCommand, char *sResult, long lLength);
  long (__stdcall *lPGSM_ExecuteCommand)(struct _modenv_ *PGEnv, char *sCommand, char *sResult, long lLength);

} PGMODENV;
```

And all I have done is this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct PGMODENV
{
    /* input data */
    public long lMajor;         /* major version of kernel */
    public long lMinor;         /* minor version of kernel */
    public long lRelease;       /* release version of kernel */

    /* updated data */
    public long lResultSize;    /* sResult buffer size */

}
```

How can I implement them in C#?

Comment: I've seen stuff like this. I would not be surprised if marshaling is impossible because you can't move the struct in memory because the buffer immediately follows the struct. The clue is there's a long for the buffer size but no buffer pointer at all.

Comment: They are function pointers, the exact equivalent in C# is a delegate object.  You have to be careful, the delegate objects you pass must have another reference somewhere so the GC doesn't clean them up and crash your program when the native code makes the function call.  Also store them in a static variable or use GCHandle.Alloc().

Comment: These structs are passed as an argument in exported functions, will they be GC? Or how shoud I prevent them from being collected?

Answer (score 2):

```
public struct PGMODENV
{
    public int lMajor; // major version of kernel
    public int lMinor; // minor version of kernel
    public int lRelease; // release version of kernel

    public int lResultSize; // sResult buffer size

    //The original C++ function pointer contained an unconverted modifier:
    //ORIGINAL LINE: int(__stdcall *lPGSM_ExecuteKernel)(struct _modenv_ *PGEnv, sbyte *sCommand, sbyte *sResult, int lLength);
    public delegate int lPGSM_ExecuteKernelDelegate(PGMODENV PGEnv, ref string sCommand, ref string sResult, int lLength);
    public lPGSM_ExecuteKernelDelegate lPGSM_ExecuteKernel;
    //The original C++ function pointer contained an unconverted modifier:
    //ORIGINAL LINE: int(__stdcall *lPGSM_ExecuteCommand)(struct _modenv_ *PGEnv, sbyte *sCommand, sbyte *sResult, int lLength);
    public delegate int lPGSM_ExecuteCommandDelegate(PGMODENV PGEnv, ref string sCommand, ref string sResult, int lLength);
    public lPGSM_ExecuteCommandDelegate lPGSM_ExecuteCommand;

}
```

Comment: This should be separate struct than `PGMODENV` ?

Comment: same, basically I converted it to class, you can use as struct, only the delegate part if for your interest I think

Comment: Got it, will test this out tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: Missed your ref keywords when passing PGMODENV to its delegate.

Comment: Correct, ref at `PGEnv`

Answer (score -2):

Try using an `IntPtr` for them since they're pointers to functions. so that it would look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct PGMODENV
{
    /* input data */
    public long lMajor;         /* major version of kernel */
    public long lMinor;         /* minor version of kernel */
    public long lRelease;       /* release version of kernel */

    /* updated data */
    public long lResultSize;    /* sResult buffer size */

    public IntPtr lPGSM_ExecuteKernel;
    public IntPtr lPGSM_ExecuteCommand;
}
```

Comment: What about the arguments?

Comment: This is just for the marshalling the struct, after that you can use Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer to convert the IntPtrs to delegate instances like @vivek nuna suggested.